After selecting "Try or install" from Install 24.04 DVD, program goes directly to "Try" and never presents a menu to select "install"
After selecting "Try or install" from Install 24.04 DVD, program goes directly to "Try" and never presents a menu  to select "install".
Ubuntu GUI comes up just fine, and everything works, but no installation is done to the hard drive.

Can you take a picture of the screen and add it to your question above? Please use the edit question function and use the "Picture" icon above the edit window to add the picture.

While running the "Try or Install", just double click on the "Install" icon on your desktop to run install.
